# How to Connect the Script in another Queries?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]

[image]

I want to Connect the 1 Script to the another Query or Script how to do that ? I Can't find the Correct Query

Comment: You can help people help you by providing the tables and columns in text. Sometimes when people see a question like this they'll just leave it because they know they have to manually type things out, where if they could copy + paste they'd answer the question.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here :/

Comment: No worries, everyone is new at some stage. Next time just give a bit more context. You provided the right information, but in addition to this just provide the querys and tables and columns as text to make it easy to copy and paste. Also I don't tend to use capital letters in column names or tables as it adds too much noise in my perspective and makes it harder to read rather than easier. Definitely use aliases though, they make reading and writing queries way easier

Comment: Thanks for the tips sir :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your original queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(HistoryOfVotersCollege.AuditorID) AS CountOfAuditorID, HistoryOfVotersCollege.AuditorID
FROM HistoryOfVotersCollege
GROUP BY HistoryOfVotersCollege.AuditorID
ORDER BY COUNT(HistoryOfVotersCollege.AuditorID) DESC; -- Query 1

SELECT AudQ1.AuditorID, AudQ1.CountOfAuditorID
FROM PresResult
WHERE AudQ1.CountOfAuditorID=(SELECT MAX(AudQ1.CountOfAuditorID) FROM AudQ1); -- Query 2
```

You can make use of table aliases (in this case "h"). This lets you declare that the column that you're referring to is from table "h", rather than using "HistoryOfVotersCollege".

```
SELECT h.AuditorID, COUNT(h.AuditorID) as count -- Query 1
FROM HistoryOfVotersCollege h
GROUP BY h.AuditorID
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

For the next bit, you can use sub-queries to create "derived tables", which is basically a temporary table. It can slow down a query if your tables are huge or your query is unoptimized, but they can also be really useful.

```
SELECT der.AuditorID, der.count FROM (
SELECT h.AuditorID, COUNT(h.AuditorID) as count -- Query 1
FROM HistoryOfVotersCollege h
GROUP BY h.AuditorID) der -- this is my derived table's alias, so i can call a column by using der.AuditorID for example
join (
SELECT h.AuditorID, COUNT(h.AuditorID) as count
FROM HistoryOfVotersCollege h
GROUP BY h.AuditorID
ORDER BY count desc
LIMIT 1 -- this is the highest count for any auditor
) der2 on der.count=der2.count;
```

This will likely perform slowly, but it's the answer to your question (in that it's a join, and using the result set from one query to join to another).
This will give you all of the `HistoryOfVotersCollege.AuditorID`s with the number of ID's that match the person with the highest.

If you only needed the person with the highest number, you could just use this:

```
SELECT h.AuditorID, COUNT(h.AuditorID) as count -- Query 1
FROM HistoryOfVotersCollege h
GROUP BY h.AuditorID
ORDER BY count desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I am new here i can't upvote i need 15 rep :/ Thanks alot.. :)